# React: Is there a way to bypass the disabled tab and peek into the content behind it on client side?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I think my question is more related to how client-side JavaScript works than specifically a React problem but I thought of this question when I am building a React Tab component.

Here is the `Tab` component I was building.

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-noyce-6kt0p

```
const Tabs = ({ data, tabPosition = 'up', disabled }) => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0)
  const tabList = (
    <div data-tab-list>
      {data.map((tab, index) => {
        const isActive = activeIndex === index
        const isDisabled = disabled.includes(index)

        return (
          <div
            data-tab
            key={index}
            className={isDisabled ? 'disabled' : isActive ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={isDisabled ? undefined : () => setActiveIndex(index)}
          >
            {tab.label}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )

  const tabPanel = <div data-tab-panels>{data[activeIndex].content}</div>

  return (
    <div data-tabs>
      {tabPosition === 'up' ? [tabList, tabPanel] : [tabPanel, tabList]}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tabs
```

As you can tell, we can disable a tab or tabs by providing this `disabled` prop, which is an array of numbers that indicates the indices of the tabs.

If I do this

```js
        <Tabs data={tabData} tabPosition="up" disabled={[2]} />
```

Then the third tab will be disabled and not clickable so that the user won't be able to see the content behind the tab, i.e. the tab panel.

However I was thinking the other day that, in fact this is all client side JavaScript code we are sending to the user's browser, so the user already has all the info in the code. It is just that React or JavaScript that got shipped prevents him/her from clicking the disabled tab. But is it true that in theory the user can peek into the content since all the code is already in the browser? I imagine if he/she set some sort of breakpoint that fires when the click happens, and modify the code locally when he/she would be able to discover the content behind the disabled tab. However I am not sure how I can achieve that.

Comment: since in this case it appears that you "disable" the tabs simply by adding a class (which I presume hides the element due to CSS rules), then all the user has to do is inspect the page and they can see the hidden content. This would be harder to do if the "disabling" actually prevented the tab being rendered, but would still be theoretically possible if the user inspected your JS code. (A lot harder presuming it's bundled and minified, but there are tools that can help with making sense of such code.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible to tinker with it and change the behavior. In your specific case, for example, you could open the [React developer tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en), select the Tabs component, and change the `disabled` prop to whatever they want and the component would re-render accordingly.

And as Robin points out in his comment, a user can simply inspect the content that's already being rendered.

As a general rule you should not rely on javascript for security purposes. If you don't want a user to access something you shouldn't be sending it to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer mode by F12 or inspect element in Browser. Go to the target element and modify the content of the code (remove disable in your case). In short you should never rely on Frontend or JS to web app security or to handle these cases place a backend validation as well.